# Bootstrap datetime picker without any javascript or jQuery

Tags: html, datetime, bootstrap-4

Is there anyway of using bootstrap to have a datetime keeper without using any javascript or jQuery? Bootstrap should have some sort of classes for that but I can't find them?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a date picker component and even if there was one I'm pretty sure it would use javascript (E.G click detection) - google tell me to tell you to look [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2):

[Vanilla JS Datepicker](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/)

A vanilla JavaScript remake of [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) and other CSS frameworks

This package is written from scratch as ECMAScript modules/Sass stylesheets to reproduce similar usability to bootstrap-datepicker.

You can get rid of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's something working without Javascript. There's a native HTML5 input type `date` but lacks wide support ( [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) ). So you  need to manage the fallback to text type input.

There are also Bootstrap [plugins](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but they all requires some Javascript and jQuery.